# Alternatives for debugging (Emulator, Real device, anything else?)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-debugging

I have a very annoying problem. To put it shortly, **I'm unable to work due to the unreliability of the Android ecosystem when it comes to debugging.**

Here is the thing:

I have a Pixel 7.

**Debugging with my office computer goes as:**

- When I connect it to my work computer (Win 11) **it constantly breaks the connection then re-connects to the PC.** This is especially annoying when I try to read logcat, or trying to run my app when the device is not connected.
- When I try to debug via Wi-Fi with the QR-code reading/connectivity, Android Studio tells me I should update "platform-tools" otherwise I cannot use this feature because: "*The system does not meet the requirements to support Wi-Fi paring. Please update to the latest version of "platform-tools" using the SDK manager.*" In the SDK download manager's SDK Tools tab, I don't see any "platform-tools", **EDIT (Thanks to Robert I found it)**: I just updated it to the latest version, (34.0.5), still the same error.
- Sometimes I just get a popup which reads: "Unknown USB device."

**Debugging with my computer at home:**

- When I bring my phone home to work on my PC at home (Win 10) the phone does very similar behavior just like with my work PC, but **the connection breaks and re-connects are much faster, like literally in 3-5 seconds.**
- The QR-code debugging sometimes work sometimes doesn't, I cannot put it any other way, and even if it is, it also **forgets/breaks connection after few minutes our hours, really unpredictable, unreliable, annoying.**

--

I tried 2 different methods, 3 different USB cables, 4 different USB slots on my 2 computers with 2 different versions of Windows and also with an additional phone (Xiaomi Mi A1) and yet **there is no variation which makes me a reliable debugging environment** for Android.

--

**Emulator:**

I'm facing the following problems with this type of debugging:

- I get a popup like every minute that says: `"System UI isn't responding"` - it is very annoying and when I demo the app the customer thinks that his app that I work on isn't working.
- The back, home, app history buttons doesn't work at all.
- There are mysterious problems every once in a while, for example: Http handshake/certificate error - strictly only ever occurred while using Emulator, never with real device. Or Firebase connectivity issues, same as above, strictly only ever occured while using Emulator.
- Customers aren't comfortable to try their app on an Emulator.
- It is painfully slow.

--

**What have I tried:**

- Reinstall Android Studio
- Update my environment, Android Studio, SDK tools, Emulator
- Deleting adb folder in myuser/android
- Trying to debug via `adb devices` to get some information about what is wrong
- Trying to connect via Wifi with command line commands
- Deleted and re-created Emulators with different Android versions
- Factory reset on my phone
- Disabling then re-enabling USB debugging and developer settings
- Bought a brand new USB cable

--

So here I am after 10+ years of Android development in the year of 2023 **and debugging for Android is still an unreliable stinking pile of crap.**

I would like to ask the community, are there any more reliable alternatives? Can you suggest me anything?

Comment: "platform-tools" you can find in SDK manager on the second tab `SDK Tools` and the full name is `Android SDK Platform-Tools`. adb usually works very reliable. Does Windows also re-detects the Pixel phone or is it just adb which dis- and reconnects?

Comment: Thank you, I updated it, still same result: "The system does not meet the requirements to support Wi-Fi pariing. Please update to the latest version of "platform-tools" using the SDK manager.

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple adb.exe versions installed on your system(s) and now those versions "fight against each other"? Especially third party emulators often contain own (older) versions of adb.exe. Also don't use USB hubs or USB ports connected via docking station. And there is still the last sentec from my first comment so check Windows device manager if the USB devices disapper/reappear on USB level (-> USb driver problem) or on adb level (USB devices are stable in device manager).

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your input, so I investigated what you suggested and Device Manager in Windows actually sometimes drop "Pixel 7" from the "USB" subcategory, so I *assume* it is not an adb issue. What can I do? - Windows also says my drivers are updated.

Comment: As multiple computers are affected and you are in an office environment I would ask your admins if there is some special USB software installed (e.g. as part of the anti-virus scanner). Also check Windows event system log, it may contain entries helping to understand the problem. If you have some on-prem admins I would try to demonstrate the problems on one of their PCs - thus "offloading" the problem, as this is not a standard behavior of USB devices, so there is something wrong with their set-up.